# What is the gspread import_csv file_id parameter?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I am trying to use the [gspread Python package](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) to import CSV data into a Google sheet from the command line.

[Using this guide](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html), I got everything working, and was able to both read and write to cells.

However updating cells 1-by-1 is too slow, so I am now trying to use the `import_csv()` method.  [The docs say](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.Client.import_csv):

> import_csv(file_id, data)
>   Imports data into the first page of the spreadsheet.
>
> Parameters: data – A CSV string of data.

`file_id` is not described here, and I can't work out what it should be.  A few other methods also use a `file_id` and for them it is described as:

> file_id – a spreadsheet ID (aka file ID.)

I am not sure where I find spreadsheet ID, and no matter what I try I get a permissions error.  Since I am able to use `update_cell()`, as described above, I think I have permissions working fine but am using the wrong `file_id`.

Here's simplified code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("SheetTitle").sheet1

# This works fine, so I think permissions etc are all set up correctly
sheet.update_cell(1, 1, 'Foo')

# Now try importing CSV data from a string
csv="""2016, 2017
1,2
3,4
"""

# Does not work
client.import_csv(sheet, csv);

# Using the spreadsheet_id in the URL as described here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id
client.import_csv('11x...', csv);

# Using the "#gid=0" value in the query string in the browser when looking at this sheet
client.import_csv(0, csv);
```

Here's the error I get, no matter which of the above I try:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./simple.py", line 22, in <module>
    client.import_csv(sheet, csv);
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 297, in import_csv
    headers=headers
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 82, in put
    return self.request('PUT', url, params=params, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 69, in request
    response.status_code, response.content))
gspread.exceptions.RequestError: (403, '403: {\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "global",\n    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",\n    "message": "Insufficient Permission"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 403,\n  "message": "Insufficient Permission"\n }\n}\n')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` to your `scope` variable and it will work:

```
scope=[
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
```

The reason you need the Google Drive in the scope is because `import_csv` actually makes an HTTP request to Google Drive API call and not to Google Sheets API.

Comment: Works!  Thank you!  This combined with the `11x...` spreadsheet_id does the trick.  Did I miss this in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: It is documented, but for other method: https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.Client.create

Answer (score 1):

Came across this while having issues of my own. Although already accepted by the author, let me share my 2 cents. 
**First: yes, you need to have the correct path in your scope. But to clarify what's the id:**

From gspread API Reference:
http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The model spreadsheet has an id field. And that's what should be used into import_csv(file_id, data) function.
Notice that there are 3 different models: 
- spreadsheet
- worksheet 
- cell.

From your sample code, you're actually getting the worksheet object.

`sheet = client.open("SheetTitle").sheet1`

Which also has an id, but I'm fairly sure this won't work.

You need to get the spreadsheet object and use its id.

`sheet = client.open("SheetTitle")
client.import_csv(sheet.id, csv);`

You can verify if the id is the same as the one you're using to input directly by printing it
`print(sheet.id)`